# Adding objects dynamically in bokeh server application

Tags: python, button, server, bokeh

I would like to add objects dynamically on the bokeh server. The example I am trying to run is the following bokeh server app:

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models import Button

def add_button():
    print("adding button")
    curdoc().add_root(column(button, button2))


 button = Button(label="Start", button_type="success")
 button.on_click(add_button)
 button2 = Button(label="Next", button_type="success")

 curdoc().add_root(column(button))
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want to keep adding a new button each time?
if so try this :

```
from bokeh.layouts import column, layout
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.models.widgets import Div


def add_button():
    print("adding button")
    layout.children.append(Button(label="Hi I am another button", button_type="success"))


button = Button(label="Click to add a button", button_type="success")
button.on_click(add_button)
layout = layout([[button]])
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

If you only wanted to add a new button once, then just append Button2.